# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema cannot be cast t

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to convert a Row in a dataframe to a case class and getting following error

> 2019-08-19 20:13:08 Executor task launch worker for task 1 ERROR
>   Executor:91 - Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1)
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema cannot
>   be cast to Models.City

`Sample Log = {"Id": "1","City": {"name": "A","state": "B"}}`

Below is the code that is reading a text file having data in *json* format which is throwing above error

```
case class City(name: String, state: String)

val file = new File("src/test/resources/log.txt")
val logs = spark.
  read.
  text(file.getAbsolutePath).
  select(col("value").
    as("body"))
import spark.implicits._
var logDF: DataFrame = spark.read.json(logs.as[String])
logDF.map(row => row.getAs[City]("City").state).show()
```

Basically I can not perform any operation on the dataframe itself due to some restrictions.
So given a row how can we cast it into a case class (i cannot use match pattern here as case class can have lot of fields and nested case classes)

Thanks in advance.
Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: See http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/ClassCastException-when-extracting-and-collecting-DF-array-column-type-td17057.html

Comment: @Robin.. thanks for the link, still i need to explicitly cast each filed to its type, is there a better way to cast the whole row into case class

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue (Spark SQL 3.1.3). The solution was to use Spark to convert Dataframe to Dataset and then access the fields.

```
import spark.implicits._
var logDF: DataFrame = spark.read.json(logs.as[String])
logDF.select("City").as[City].map(city => city.state).show()
```